# MaminGL OpenGL err = 1280 (Invalid Enum) - Animated Plane with Texture

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, rendering, manim, python-moderngl

I'm getting `invalid enum error` using maningl.

I have created an animated wave with video as texture.

Code works well with a  short animation of around 5 seconds.
This is the result:
But with more than 10 seconds it throws `invalid enum error`

Animation length is controlled with method `self.wait` in `PinkyWaving` class.

[Wave with video as texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmFIJ.gif)

The error:

```
  self.construct()
  File "pinky_waving.py", line 119, in construct
    self.wait(10)
  File "f:\instalaciones\anaconda\envs\manim2\lib\site-packages\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 417, in wrapper
    func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "f:\instalaciones\anaconda\envs\manim2\lib\site-packages\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 508, in wait
    self.emit_frame()
  File "f:\instalaciones\anaconda\envs\manim2\lib\site-packages\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 179, in emit_frame
    self.file_writer.write_frame(self.camera)
  File "f:\instalaciones\anaconda\envs\manim2\lib\site-packages\manimlib\scene\scene_file_writer.py", line 238, in write_frame
    raw_bytes = camera.get_raw_fbo_data()
  File "f:\instalaciones\anaconda\envs\manim2\lib\site-packages\manimlib\camera\camera.py", line 294, in get_raw_fbo_data
    gl.glBindFramebuffer(gl.GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, self.fbo_msaa.glo)
  File "src/errorchecker.pyx", line 58, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
        err = 1280,
        description = b'numeraci\xf3n no v\xe1lida',
        baseOperation = glBindFramebuffer,
        cArguments = (GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 2)
)
```

I'm using Python 3.8, ManimGL v1.5.0 and moderngl version: 5.7.2.

Where animation is made `pinky.py`.

```
from manimlib import *

VIDEO_FRAMES  = 'pinky_60fps-opencv'
TEXTURES = os.listdir(VIDEO_FRAMES)
N = len(TEXTURES)
FRAME_INDEX = 0 


class TexturedPlaneWavingVideo(TexturedSurface):
    CONFIG = {   
        'waving_plane_config':
            {
            "u_range": (-5*2,5*2),
            "v_range": (-5*2,5*2),
            "resolution": (32,32),
            "color": BLUE_E,
            "opacity": 0.85,
            }
    }
    def __init__(self, phi=0, height_factor=1.0, d=1.0, alpha=0.1,scale_factor = 0.5, init_frame= None,**kwargs):
        """
        init_frame: str
            frame used as texture
        """
        digest_config(self,self.CONFIG)
        self.init_frame = init_frame

        # Parameters
        # heigth of wave
        self.height_factor = height_factor
        self.d = d
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.phi = phi
        #overall scale of plane
        self.scale_factor = scale_factor
        
        # Initialize as a plane
        surface = ParametricSurface(
            uv_func = self.wave_func,
            **self.waving_plane_config).scale(self.scale_factor)

        self.surface = surface
       
        super().__init__(uv_surface= surface,
            image_file = os.path.join(VIDEO_FRAMES,self.init_frame))


    def update_wave(self,dt):
        self.phi += 4*dt
        global FRAME_INDEX
        FRAME_INDEX= (FRAME_INDEX+1)%N
        
        texture = TEXTURES[FRAME_INDEX]
        texture_path =os.path.join(VIDEO_FRAMES, TEXTURES[FRAME_INDEX])
       

        # Create a new TexturedPlaneWavingVideo
        plane = TexturedPlaneWavingVideo(
            phi=self.phi, height_factor=self.height_factor, d=self.d ,alpha=self.alpha,scale_factor = self.scale_factor, init_frame=texture )
        
        self.init_frame = texture

        
        self.texture_paths = {
            "LightTexture": get_full_raster_image_path(texture_path),
            "DarkTexture": get_full_raster_image_path(texture_path),}

        self.become(plane)
        
        self.init_shader_data()
        
       
    def plane_func(self,u,v):
        return np.array([
            u,
            v,
            0])

    def wave_func(self, u, v):

        return (u,
                v,
                np.sin((np.sqrt(u**2/self.d + v ** 2 / self.d) + self.phi)) * self.height_factor + self.alpha)

    def wave_func_np(self,u,v):
        return  np.array(
            [u,
             v,
             np.sin( (np.sqrt(u**2/self.d + v ** 2 / self.d ) + self.phi) ) * self.height_factor + self.alpha])

    def waving(self,speed = 1):
        """
        speed: float
            speed of waving animation
        """
        self.add_updater(lambda m,dt:self.update_wave(dt*speed)  )

        
    def stop_waving(self):
        self.clear_updaters()

class PinkyWaving(ThreeDScene):
    def construct(self):
        p = TexturedPlaneWavingVideo(phi=0, height_factor=3.0, d=1.0, alpha=0.1,scale_factor = 0.5,init_frame="frame0-00-00.00.jpg")
        
        self.play(ShowCreation(p))
        
        p.waving()
        
        self.wait(10)
```

Download an extract the images to reproduce the error:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_kUcDP5D4-7LXi7bbpnjdobl4ajHTOMr/view?usp=sharing

Run the command `manimgl pinky.py PinkyWaving -w`

Each `texture_path` is a path to a jpg image.

I expected to produce an animation with the full video, 2 minutes, but if the animation passes the 10 seconds it throws `Invalid enum`.

Comment: That's basically a hack in manim with pyopengl. Try asking in the manim discord and/or make an issue on github.